# OS X terminal: stuck in a ">" line

Tags: macos, terminal, curl

I trying to execute a Curl command (to ElasticSearch REST API) that looks like:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search”?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}
'
```

I get the angle bracket `>` on each line, and can't figure out how to execute the command that I've entered from there. I found this [page with](http://www.mac-forums.com/macos-operating-system/300551-terminal-stuck-line.html) some info, but I tried the suggestions, and it's not working.

`Control + D` gives me:

> -bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>   -bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Writing EOF, then `Control + D` gives me the same.

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong again. The only problem was the smart quote, which may have been added by a text editor along the way. Agh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample is this:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search”?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}
'
```

That second quote after `_search` is a “smart quote” (ie: `”`) instead of a straight quote (ie: `"`). So it should be; note how I added the quote after `?pretty` like this:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}
'
```

But that said, it makes little to no sense why there are *any* quotes around that URL since it can easily work like this:

```
curl -X GET localhost:9200/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }
}
'
```

Comment: While the host portion doesn't need to be quoted, the question mark just after it sort of should be (technically it's a wildcard) although it's unlikely to matter. Personally, I'd quote the entire argument (using plain ASCII quotes).

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to achieve that:

### 1. Read from stdin

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-
```

Then you can type the JSON code and press Ctrl+D to send.

You can also pipe it from another program, for instance:

```
some-node-app-that-outputs-json | curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-
```

### 2. Read from file

You can also write it to a file and pass the file:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @yourfile.json
```

Comment: Regarding `curl -XGET`, actually it's the same as `curl -X GET`. The `-X` parameter expects what follows to be the method, so it doesn't matter to curl if GET is separated from parameter or not.

Answer (score 1):

The second "double quote" is wrong. Since the quotes aren't closed, you get `$PS2` as a prompt so you can close it.

```
$ charinfo '"localhost:9200/_search”'
U+0022 QUOTATION MARK [Po]
U+006C LATIN SMALL LETTER L [Ll]
U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O [Ll]
 ...
U+0072 LATIN SMALL LETTER R [Ll]
U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C [Ll]
U+0068 LATIN SMALL LETTER H [Ll]
U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK [Pf]
```